# Parsing Twilio statuscallback Call/Conference events

Tags: rest, api, twilio, twilio-api

I'm creating a call using Twilio's Java lib like so:

```
 PhoneNumber phoneNumberTo = new PhoneNumber(to);
 PhoneNumber phoneNumberFrom = new PhoneNumber(from);
 com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call call = new CallCreator(phoneNumberTo, phoneNumberFrom, URI.create(twimlUrl))
     .setStatusCallback(URI.create(twStatusCallbackUrl))
     .setStatusCallbackEvent(Arrays.asList(
         com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call.Event.ANSWERED.toString(),
         com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call.Event.COMPLETED.toString(),
         com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call.Event.INITIATED.toString(),
         com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Call.Event.RINGING.toString()))
     .create(this.client);
```

I get call events as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Is there a best practise way to parse the sent form data into some sort of Twilio call event object?

Example of the status sent by Twilio:

```
START TIME        =09-Jan-2017 16:00:16
    requestURI=/api/calls/12345/
      authType=null
characterEncoding=UTF-8
 contentLength=591
   contentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
   contextPath=
        header=accept=*/*
        header=cache-control=max-age=259200
        header=content-length=591
        header=content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
        header=host=api.example.com
        header=x-twilio-signature=BLAH/BLAH
        header=user-agent=TwilioProxy/1.1
        header=connection=close
        locale=en_US
        method=POST
     parameter=Called=+44123456789
     parameter=ToState=London
     parameter=CallerCountry=GB
     parameter=Direction=outbound-api
     parameter=Timestamp=Mon, 09 Jan 2017 16:00:16 +0000
     parameter=CallbackSource=call-progress-events
     parameter=CallerState=London
     parameter=ToZip=
     parameter=SequenceNumber=3
     parameter=CallSid=BLAHBLAH
     parameter=To=+44123456789
     parameter=CallerZip=
     parameter=ToCountry=GB
     parameter=ApiVersion=2010-04-01
     parameter=CalledZip=
     parameter=CalledCity=
     parameter=CallStatus=completed
     parameter=Duration=1
     parameter=From=+44123456789
     parameter=CallDuration=5
     parameter=AccountSid=BLAHBLAH
     parameter=CalledCountry=GB
     parameter=CallerCity=
     parameter=Caller=+44123456789
     parameter=FromCountry=GB
     parameter=ToCity=
     parameter=FromCity=
     parameter=CalledState=London
     parameter=FromZip=
     parameter=FromState=London
      pathInfo=null
      protocol=HTTP/1.1
   queryString=null
    remoteAddr=X.X.X.X
    remoteHost=X.X.X.X
    remoteUser=null
requestedSessionId=null
        scheme=http
    serverName=api.example.com
    serverPort=8082
   servletPath=/api/calls/12345/
      isSecure=false
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Maintaining state for the events returned by statusCallbacks for example, is something you must build into your app.

Check out the following example given in the docs for [making a call and monitoring progress events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter).

```
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.CallFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Call;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.CallList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class Example {

  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    // Build a filter for the CallList
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+14155551212"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+18668675309"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Method", "GET"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallback", "https://www.myapp.com/events"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackMethod", "POST"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "initiated"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "ringing"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "answered"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "completed"));


    CallFactory callFactory = client.getAccount().getCallFactory();
    Call call = callFactory.create(params);
    System.out.println(call.getSid());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm sure that's just the deprecated way of making a call (v5). It's does exactly what I'm doing above and also doesn't show how to handle the callback events coming back. Was hoping the API intercepted the statuscallback events and kept an internal model of the call updated somewhere. Don't suppose that's the case?